# Swift How can I check a variable for multiple string conditions

Tags: string, swift, dictionary

Currently I'm checking if a key in a dictionary contains a certain string values:

```
if dict["eventCode"] == "OFF" || dict["eventCode"] == "DHD" || dict["eventCode"] == "SBY"
  {
     // do something
  }
else if dict["eventCode"] == "DHT" || dict["eventCode"] == "SLV" || dict["eventCode"] == "CLV"
 {
   // do something else
}
```

the list of possible values are about 10, the if statement is working but lengthy and prone to type errors.

What is the best way to refractor this kind of "if statement" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`switch` on String?

```
guard let val = dict["eventCode"] as? String else { return }

switch val {
case "OFF", "DHD", "SBY":
    print("something")

case "DHT", "SLV", "CLV":
    print("something else")

default:
    print("default")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let check1 = ["OFF", "DHD", "SBY"]
let check2 = ["DHT", "SLV", "CLV"]

if check1.contains(dict["eventCode"] ?? "") {
    print("found in 1")
} else if check2.contains(dict["eventCode"] ?? "") {
    print("found in 2")
}
```

But in my opinion this looks ugly..

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a `switch` statement:

```
switch dict["eventCode"] {
    case let ec? where ec == "OFF" || ec == "DHD" || ec == "SBY":
        // do something
    case let ec? where ec == "DHT" || ec == "SLV" || ec == "CLV":
        // do something else
    default:
        break 
}
```

While it isn't necessarily less code than a series of `if-else` branches, I find the logic cleaner and easier to read.

EDIT:

@Eendje's answer is also very good, and could be combined with the `switch`:

```
let check1 = ["OFF", "DHD", "SBY"]
let check2 = ["DHT", "SLV", "CLV"]

switch dict["eventCode"] {
    case let ec? where check1.contains(ec):
        // do something
    case let ec? where check2.contains(ec):
        // do something else
    default:
        break 
}
```